# To write the output of this function into a pdf file in R

Tags: r, function, pdf

I have written the following function,

```
CSVDimension <- function(.csv) {
  csv <- read.csv(.csv)
  dimValue <- dim(csv)
  print("The dimension of the dataset is:")
  headValue <- head(csv)
  print("The head of the dataset is:")
  return(list(dimValue,headValue))
}
```

This function prints the dimension of a given dataset when we run,

```
> CSVDimension("path/to/file/dataset.csv")
```

My next step is to print this result on to a properly-formatted pdf file.

How can you write the output of the function `CSVDimension` into a pdf file in R?

Comment: You can use `rmarkdown`, see here: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-1.html

Comment: I will have a look at it. How exactly do I print the output of the function to the pdf? The link you provided takes me to the homepage of R-md, which is fine. I just want you to point me to the exact place.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 You could have just suggested an edit; downvoting won't help the quality in anyway.

Comment: @PragyadityaDas Done. My point was to make the title clear that this is not a general method to write into a pdf file but just for this case so *this function*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have [pandoc](http://pandoc.org) installed (and in your path), you can modify your function to

```
    CSVDimension <- function(.csv, .pdf) {
      csv <- read.csv(.csv)
      dimValue <- dim(csv)
      msg <- paste("The dimension of the dataset is:", paste(dimValue, collapse = " : "))
      print(msg)
      md <- sub("\\.pdf", ".md", .pdf)
      cat(msg, file = md)
      system(paste("pandoc -o", .pdf, md))
      return(dimValue)
}
```

where .csv is the path to your csv file, and .pdf the path to the resulting pdf output.

Comment: Should I install using the .msi installer? I am on a windows 8 laptop.

Comment: Error : Error in sub("\\.pdf", ".md", .pdf) : 
  argument ".pdf" is missing, with no default

Comment: .pdf is an argument with no default: use that to give the desired path for the pdf output. No idea about windows, but msi is probably fine. NB: check, if the installer puts the pandoc executable in your path, if not, adapt line starting with `system` accordingly.

Comment: I will just add a small modification to the above.

Comment: I did some changes in the function you provided, I added `msg1 <- paste("The dimension of the dataset is:", paste(dimValue, collapse = " : "))`, then I added `headValue <- head(csv)` and wrote `msg2 <- paste("The head of the dataset is:", paste(headValue, collapse = " : "))`, then I added `cat(msg1, msg2 , file = md)`. The code runs properly, but the output pdf file looks odd. `The dimension of the dataset is: 244 : 8 The head of the dataset is: 1:4 : c(16.99, 10.34, 21.01,23.68) : c(1.01, 1.66, 3.5, 3.31) : c(1, 2, 2, 2) : c(1,
1, 1, 1) : c(3, 3, 3, 3) : c(2, 2, 2, 2) : c(2, 3, 3, 2)`.